# Patch in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I must create in SpringBoot this request at `PATCH`:

```
{
  link: string
}
```

I try create my function like this:

```
    @PatchMapping
    public void updateMovie(@RequestBody String link)
```

but my request is invalid and in swagger looks like this:

```
    "string"
```

Comment: Hi, there is not enough information to help with troubleshooting. Can you add any stacktrace information (maybe in the logs) you might be getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create DTO (Data Transfer Object) with field String link in it. Then use it as request body.

Something like this:

```
public class LinkDto {
   private String link;
}
```

And then your controller endpoint:

```
@PatchMapping

public void updateMovie(@RequestBody LinkDto link)
```